# Function to create xml with column names as elements

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sqlxml

I need to write a basic t-sql function *f* that receives the following parameters:

```
(Id int, CustomerId int, Delay int)
```

and creates, for *f(1, 125, 32)*, the following xml, to be later inserted into a xml column in a table:

```
<content>   
<column name="Id">1</column>   
<column name="CustomerId">125</column>   
<column name="Delay">125</column>   
</content>
```

Any ideas on how to attack the problem?

Comment: You don't you just concatenate those IDs, casting them as VARCHAR. E.g. CAST(id AS VARCHAR)

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from (values
    (@Id, 'Id'), (@CustomerId, 'CustomerId'), (@Delay, 'Delay')
) as a([@Name], [text()])
for xml path('column'), root('content')
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/25882)</kbd>**